# what services start during pantheon-session startup ?

Tags: startup, window-manager

for some performance reasons, I have installed icewm on elementary os hera .
I want to discover which services start for a pantheon-session by default , and enable them in icewm-session manually .
what are these services and is this possible to start them manually?
for example what is the default compositor and how can be enabled by command line?

here is

```
inxi -Fxz
```

output of my system :

`System:    Host: Master-PC Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: IceWM 1.4.3.0~pre-20180217 Distro: elementary OS 5.1 Hera
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 33668DG v: ThinkPad Edge E530c serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 33668DG serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: J0ET15WW (1.05 ) date: 08/02/2013
Battery    BAT0: charge: 28.2 Wh 100.0% condition: 28.2/40.4 Wh (70%) model: LGC 45N1049 status: Full
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-3320M (-MT-MCP-) arch: Ivy Bridge rev.9 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10375
           clock speeds: max: 3300 MHz 1: 1211 MHz 2: 1245 MHz 3: 1260 MHz 4: 1301 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF119M [GeForce 610M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 610M/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-37-generic
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: bcma-pci-bridge bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlp3s0b1 state: down mac: 
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 port: 2000 bus-ID: 0c:00.0
           IF: enp12s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (39.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5000LPVX size: 500.1GB temp: 44C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 7.8G (29%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 6.29GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda4
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:45C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 225 Uptime: 33 min Memory: 1620.0/3541.3MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (zsh 5.4.2) inxi: 2.3.56`